# How to keep track of maven dependency updates in projects?

Tags: security, dependency-management, maven, jenkins, gitlab

How do you keep track of maven dependency versions?

Let's say you are using version `1.0.5` of an library.

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>groupIdName</groupId>
    <artifactId>artecfact-id</artifactId>
    <version>1.0.5</version>
</dependency>
```

But some people find a very bad security bug in version `1.0.5` and they release version `1.0.6` with a bugfix for this security vulnerability.

How do you manage in your project to **know** that there is a new **important** version, where it's very important to update?

I'm sure, no one is looking every week: Is there a new update to all the projects?
Even with watching the github projects, it will end up in a mess, because there are too many dependencies to watch in big projects.

We are using `Gitlab` and `Jenkins` in our environment, so if there are good plugins for that tools, or something else like `Sonar` can help here, let me know.

Looking forward for this discussion!
(I hope the softwareengineering on stackexchange is the right place for this discussion)

Comment: Please check [these](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3516538/how-to-check-pom-xml-for-updated-dependencies) [two](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2687220/maven-check-for-updated-dependencies-in-repository) stackoverflow answers..

Comment: can't mark my own question on duplicate, because it's on StackOverflow not here... But still in need for a tool for Jenkins / Gitlab (I saw VersionEyes from one of this answers.. will try that as stand alone)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Consider using dependency-check

https://www.owasp.org/index.php/OWASP_Dependency_Check

It has a Maven plugin and command line tool. You can use it to warn you if you use "dangerous" dependency versions in a build. The list is updated every day.

Comment: exactly what I needed. thanks for answering this old question!

Answer (score 1):

I don't want to veer into product recommendations but there are vendor solutions that allow you to run these kinds of checks.  [One that I am slightly familiar with](https://www.sonatype.com/nexus-firewall) consists of a private proxy maven repository.  You point your build server to it and have all the developers use it in lieu of maven central.  When a pom references a risky dependency it will fail the build.  It offers the ability for privileged users to manage rules and exceptions.